# not able to run linkedin company profile script

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I copied the code from this link(https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/jymbii) by giving company name and clicking the Get Code button. It generated the code given below

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/JYMBII" data-companyid="5818" data-format="inline"></script>
```

I pasted this code in tag of a html file and then run the html file in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but all browser gave a blank page as output.

How should I use this in my jsp/html file, so that it could generate the job-posting feed.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just add those two script tags in the `<body>` tag. If you have added them in the `<head>` tag it will not work

Comment: Make sure you are accesing the file with a `http` or `https` protocol( I mean run in on a local server). Just opening the html file directly from the file system will not work

also don't save the `in.js ` file on your file system

Comment: How are you accessing the HTML file? Looks like you are not accessing it from a local web server

Comment: It will not work locally as I said earlier. YOu have to put in a server, and access from server

Comment: You can run on Apache server, or XAMPP. But I am sure you have some webserver like tomcat etc, other wise how are planning to allow others to access this page